# Error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('rest_framework>=3.6.3')

Tags: python, django, pip, pypi

i am trying to build a python package and my following is my setup.py

```
setup(
    name='django-sso_consumer',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    license='BSD License',  # example license
    description='A simple Django app for sso_consumenr and hooks',
    long_description=README,
    url='https://www.example.com/',
    author='Paksign',
    author_email='shoaib@wukla.com',
    classifiers=[
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Framework :: Django :: 1.5',  # replace "X.Y" as appropriate
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',  # example license
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP',
        'Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content',
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'wukla_utils',
        'rest_framework>=3.6.3',
        'django>=1.11.3'
    ]
)
```

but upon running `sudo python setup.py develop` i am unable to install it and it yields the following error:

> Reading https://pypi.org/simple/ No local packages or working download
>   links found for rest_framework>=3.6.3 error: Could not find suitable
>   distribution for Requirement.parse('rest_framework>=3.6.3')

Answer (score 4):

Try to change it to `djangorestframework>=3.6.3`.